# What is a Master-Backup Clustering Model

Tags: tomcat, webserver, cluster-computing

What is a Master-Backup Clustering Model?

I was reading: http://www.datadisk.co.uk/html_docs/java_app/tomcat6/tomcat6_clustering.htm
And it makes mention to it on the 4th paragraph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a load balancing pattern for high-availability of the cluster.

Professional Tomcat (2004 Edition) on [Google Books](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=c022aMuJBU4C&lpg=PA460&ots=vZrHFa_zVH&dq=One%20machine%20is%20designated%20as%20the%20master%20server%20and%20processes%20incoming%20requests.%20The%20rest%20of%20the%20machines%20are%20backup%20servers&pg=PA460#v=onepage&q&f=true) has an explanation - shown below.

[image: Master Backup]

Comment: That's interesting, it's sounds oddly like the 'fail-over' cluster model?

Comment: yes it does, doesnt it? The subtle difference as I make out (from that same URL) is that Master-Backup is the server topological set-up whereas Failover is the actual event of copying over the sessions etc from the Master to the Backup